# Align stanzas horizontally

Tags: lilypond

I have typeset some notes using Lilypond. Unfortunately, the stanza numbers do not align over several lines. Here is a stripped-down example:

```
\score {
  \new Staff <<
    \new Voice \relative c'' {
      \key d \major
      \time 2/2
      \partial 4 d,4 | fis4 g4 a4 a4 | g2 fis4 g4 \break
      \omit Score.Clef
      fis4 d4 e4 e4 | fis2 r4 d4 | fis4 g4 \bar "" \break
      a4 a4 | g2 fis4 g4 | fis4 d4 e4 e4 \break
      d2 r4 a'4 | d2 cis2 | b4 a4 a4 (gis4) | a2 r4 fis4 \bar "|."
    }

    \addlyrics { \teeny {
      \set stanza = #"1 "
      Gott, der nach sei -- nem Bil -- de aus
      \set stanza = #"1 "
      Staub den Men -- schen macht, hat uns seit
      \set stanza = #"1 "
      je zur Freu -- de ein -- an -- der zu -- ge --
      \set stanza = #"1 "
      dacht. Er fügt euch nun zu -- sam -- men, lässt
    } }

  >>
  \layout {
    indent = #0
    \context {
      \Score
      \omit BarNumber
    }
  }
}
```

This is rendered by Lilypond like so:

[image]

So the question is: How can those little `1.` numbers be aligned horizontally?

Answer (score 0):

This can be fixed somehow by using left-aligned lyrics instead of the default centered ones (http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.18/Documentation/source/Documentation/snippets/text#text-lyrics-alignment). I don't know if left-aligned lyrics are desirable/acceptable in your case.

Another option would be to use numbering in the first line only. That's what I've seen in all song and hymn books I've read, but maybe you have your reasons to keep stanza numbers in each line.

Comment: Unfortunately the numbers must be on each line as the source is numbered the same way :-/